# Add background to the text using Magick++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

Im trying to add red background under the text using Magick++. My simple code is:

```
Magick::Image img( Geometry(800,200), Color("white") );

img.strokeWidth(12);
img.font("Helvetica");
img.fontPointsize(font_size);

img.draw(Magick::DrawableTextUnderColor(Magick::Color("red")));
img.draw(Magick::DrawableText(25, 25,  "Some text") );

img.write("file.png");
```

It prints text OK, but the text does not have red background. Current result is this:

[image]

However, I would like to have the text with background, something like this (background photo shopped for the example)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Instead of drawing things one-by-one, make a list of Drawable items, and than draw everything at once:

```
list<Magick::Drawable> to_draw;

to_draw.push_back(Magick::DrawableText(25, 25,  "Some text"));
to_draw.push_back(Magick::DrawableTextUnderColor("red"));

img.draw(to_draw);
```

Comment: I have a problem with that code: "error: no matching member function for call to 'draw'". ImageMagick 7.0.5, OS X 10.12.3

Comment: it should be `std::vector` instead of `std::list`

Answer (score 2):

- Here is a solution of your problem,

  ```
  Image img(Geometry(800, 800), Color("white"));
  img.font("Helvetica");
  img.fillColor(Color("firebrick"));
  img.strokeColor(Color("red"));
  img.draw(Magick::DrawableText(25, 25,  "Some text") );
  img.write("text.png");
  ```